# Add a React component to the JS project

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add a react component to a php/js project.
Have added a new folder, created a new react app and updated the component. 
The component works fine through `npm start` but I need to connect existing JS files to this component, that's what I am not sure how to deal with? have to build the component? if so, how it should be added to the main JS file.

FYI, tried to define react and babel in script, but the issue was couldn't use `import` so I had to add everything in a file, which doesn't sound very clean.

would be appreciated if you have any idea

Here is main.js

```
<div id=root></div>
<script src="../js/missions/src/App.js"></script>
```

and This is the react component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Test</h1>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are working is the normal approach to create a single page application. If you want to make your React app works with your existing php / any other MVC frameworks, you will need to look at server side rendering techniques by React.

Here is a blog to help you understand how it works with Node.js: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/demystifying-reacts-server-side-render-de335d408fe4

I found a repo that may help you with your PHP project:
https://github.com/Limenius/ReactRenderer

This is the doc of ReactDOMServer from the official website: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html

You should still be able to access to some of the existing js functions such as event listeners, DOM manipulations etc if you render your component at the server side.